# Break ssh command from within a script and save debug log to a file

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to write a bash script that runs ssh command with debug (`ssh -vvv`) against a specified host/hosts.
I am not trying to login to the server, but rather just trying to see what all kex, mac and ciphers does the server offer.

I did create a script to find the kex algos after negotiation using the -G option.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `cat servers.txt`;
do echo "### $f ###";
        echo -e "kexalgorithms"
        result=$(ssh -G $f uname -a | grep kexalgorithms)
        echo $result;
done
```

However, I now realize that this output with depend on the ssh config on the local machine and will not give me the exact kex offered by the remote server.

If I do a `ssh -vvv <host>` it would give this info in the line

debug2: **peer server KEXINIT proposal**

***debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256***

debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers

But, if run `ssh -vvv` from the script it will be stuck at username/password prompt.

Is there any way that I can save the standard output till the password prompt to a file (probably with the host name as the filename) and break the script run at a password prompt?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable `PasswordAuthentication` and `PubkeyAuthentication` and use GNU `grep`:

```
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -vv YOUR-SSH-SERVER 2>&1 | grep -m 1 -Po 'KEX algorithms: \K.*'
```

Output (e.g.):

`curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16`

Comment: Hi Cyrus, 

This does work. I am testing this further and will keep you posted. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. I definitely recommend testing it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Get all supported algorithms for key exchange from remote ssh-server with `nmap`:

```
nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos -p 22 YOUR-SSH-SERVER \
  | awk -v a='kex_algorithms:' '$2==a{getline; while( $0~/^\| {7}/ ){ print $2; getline }}'
```

Output (e.g.):

```
curve25519-sha256
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ecdh-sha2-nistp521
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
```